# Oracle Resource Manager CPU Usage plan

Tags: oracle, performance, cpu, resourcemanager

I have a question regarding Oracle Resource Manager and how it works
more or less I am interested in CPU usage because I can see a 'complicated' design in our resource manager and I want to know if I understand this right:
This is how our Resource Manager Looks like

```
Group     Level1    Level2    Level3    Level4    Level5
Sys          50%        0%        0%        0%        0%
Support       0%       50%        0%        0%        0%
ETL1          0%        0%       15%       40%        0%
BI Tool       0%        0%       60%       20%      100%
ETL3          0%        0%        5%       30%        0%
```

Can I expect for level 3 and 4 for example that when I really use 100% of CPU (and sys and support is not working) that ETL3 would get 5% of Level 3 and then there are 20% left that will go to level 4 where ETL3 would get 30% of 20% so 6% so it will get 11% CPU Usage?

Thanks for helping me to understand!